# .NET - Is Microsoft.Web.WebView2 open source?

Tags: .net, webview2

Is Microsoft.Web.WebView2 open source? If yes, where is the source located? I'm trying to troubleshoot what I believe is a bug.

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback

Comment: Thanks, Pavel. I suppose the answer is no, although the feedback is open source

Answer (score 0):

No. Microsoft.Web.WebView2 package, which contains WebView2, is not open.

Although WebView2 (and Microsoft Edge) is based on Chromium/Blink, which is open source, Microsoft has not publicly released WebView2's source.